# catalog page product image is not showing the path for media is taking

Tags: image, media-images

I was trying to take media backup of my magento website from the server and deploying on my localhost machine but in the catalog page product image is not showing the path for media is taking from the below url

http://127.0.0.1/Storemediaall/media/C:/wamp64/www/Storemediaall/media/product/aab/advantagec05.jpg

i have done with the web cofig /media path but still it is not showing, can any one please help in this

Comment: have you found the solution? I am having the same issue